# Arangodb is full of disk space

Tags: arangodb

I built Arangodb3 on centos7.4, using the default configuration, now 500G disk has been used up, but the amount of data is not large, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please try to be a little more specific. You built ArangoDB yourself instead of using the distributed binary? Have you stripped the binaries?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile ArangoDB yourselves (instead of using our precompiled binary packages), you only have to keep the source and the build-folder until you ran

```
make install
```

after that you can remove it again to free up disk space.

Please note that after removing the source and build folder you will have to re-download (or `git clone https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb.git`) the source again, and re-compile it once more completely which will take longer than an incremental build.